# clear test history intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, automated-tests

Intellij keeps track of test (JUnit) history, which is very nice...

But it registers failing tests as 'problem', which get triggered by commit-checks. I want to commit non-working tests at the end of the day, so I want to be able to clear the test-history.

However, I can't find that option anywhere, nor does 'delete' work on the selected test-run.

How to clear all of the test history?

Answer (score 3):

In Settings, Editor, Inspections, select "Failed line in test" and turn the severity down to "Weak Warning"

Comment: Not the answer to my question, but a solution to my direct problem  :) Thanks! (I'll wait for an answer that allows me to clear the results before accepting)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to comment the non working tests, then run it again and commit it with only working tests.

Also the put TODO in the comments of the non working tests, so that you know that you have to check them later on.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for the workaround, I figured I could ultimately do that :) The `TODO` is not necessary, the tests will fail again when I run them.

Comment: The TODO was meant as a reminder for when the test is commented like: `//TODO: Enable Test again`

Comment: Ah ;) then it makes sense

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).